# non breaking space between labels create a visible space when rendered

Tags: html, css

Not sure if I am just missing something here, but in my app, I am going:

```
<label>Hello</label>
<label>World</label>
```

and when they are rendered, it looks like:

> |Hello| |World|

There is some ugly space between the two labels (Assuming I give them a border, or background color);

If I move the labels to be on the same line, it works fine.

```
<label>Hello</label><label>World</label>
```

Is there anyway to remove this space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how inline elements are rendered by the browser — non-repeating white spaces are rendered as is, regardless of whether is it a space, a tab or a new line.

The most reliable way is to use choose to display the labels are block-level elements, and float them. However, you should note that by floating the labels you are going to take them out of the document flow, causing the parent to collapse — this can be fixed with the good old [clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), or simply using `overflow: hidden` on the parent element.

Let's say your markup looks like this:

```
<form>
    <label>Hello</label>
    <label>World</label>
</form>
```

The CSS that will fix the issue will be:

```
form {
    overflow: hidden;
}
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7RXDm/

---

Alternatively, you can declare a negative margin on them with a value that approximates the space introduced by browser rendering, but it is unpredictable especially when dealing with flexible font sizes, different font families as well as different zoom levels.